# How to use TypesSript in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

### How to `require` a TypeScript class in a Node CommonJS JavaScript file?

Working with `mongoose`, in my TS code, I do:

```
// user.model.ts
export const UserModel = model<User>('User', schema);
```

In my JS code:

```js
// user.controller.js
const UserModel = require('./user.model');
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './user.model'
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

---

When I add `.ts`:

```js
// user.controller.js
const UserModel = require('./user.model.ts');
                                     ^^^
```

The error message changes:

```
user.model.ts:1
import { Document, model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Are you using `ts-node` or regular `node`? What version?

Comment: @jered regular `node`, `v16.13.2`

Comment: Transpile the TypeScript code and import the resulting JavaScript code.

Comment: You can't use TypeScript code directly in vanilla JS without transpiling it first. Either switch to `ts-node` or use TypeScript to transpile your TS files first.

Comment: @jered if you post your comment as answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript files must be "transpiled" via the TypeScript compiler before they can be run or imported into vanilla JS. If you're working in Node, one of the best ways to do this is to utilize `ts-node`, which will automatically just-in-time transform your scripts as it runs them. See their docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).